# Racket Install plai-typed

Tags: racket, plai

i have some issue to install the package `plai-typed` on `racket`.

Here is the **error**:

> Resolving "plai-typed" via
>   http://download.racket-lang.org/releases/6.3/catalog/ Resolving
>   "plai-typed" via http://pkgs.racket-lang.org Using
>   cached15139380901513938090239 for
>   github://github.com/mflatt/plai-typed/master The following out-of-date
>   packages are listed as dependencies of plai-typed and they will be
>   automatically updated:    scribble-lib (have 1.12, need 1.16) drracket
>   install: package installed in a different scope   package:
>   scribble-lib   current scope: user   installed in scope: installation

Comment: Update racket to a version after 6.4. The latest version is 6.11.

Comment: Thx it's working ! :)